# Describing maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ up to homotopy

Tags: homotopy-theory

I'm trying to describe continuous maps $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, where $f^{-1}(0) = \{0\}$, up to homotopy.

Without the condition that $f^{-1}(0) = \{0\}$, it seems that all maps are homotopic to each other; since all the homotopy groups of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ are trivial, and this is evidence that maps between the two spaces are trivial up to homotopy too (though I can't seem to come up with a proof of this fact?)

With the condition that $f^{-1}(0) = \{0\}$, I'm not sure how I would go about approaching this problem. The main thing that seems to cloud my vision is that I can only really imagine the cases where $n,m \leq 3$; and even then I'm not sure that my intuition holds.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it may be equivalent to computing $\pi_{n-1}(S^{m-1})$.
Each $f$ restricts to a map from $\Bbb  R^n-\{0\}$ to $\Bbb  R^m-\{0\}$ to
and these spaces are homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-1}$ and $S^{m-1}$.
Conversely each $g:S^{n-1}\to S^{m-1}$ extends radially to an $f$ of your form.

I haven't checked the details on whether these correspondences are preserved by homotopy etc.

Comment: In particular, you have a map $r: [(\Bbb R^n-\{0\}, 0), (\Bbb R^m - \{0\}] -> [S^{n-1}, S^{m-1}]$ gotten by restriction, and a map $i$ in the other direction (using radial extension), but while it's clear that $r \circ i = id$, it's not clear that $i \circ r$ is homotopic to the identity.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: For $f, g: R^n \to R^k$, consider, for each $P \in R^n$, the line segment from $f(P)$ to $g(P)$ as a parameterized arc (with parameter $s$, say, running from $0$ to $1$). Suppose that $f(0) = g(0) = 0$. What will this line segment look like?

Comment: Is the idea that the collection of line segments from f(P) to g(P) for all P parametised by s describes a homotopy from f to g? What if the origin lies on the line segment between f(P) and g(P) though?

Comment: As Joshua said, that is the whole point. We know that $H(x,s)=sf(x)+(1-s)g(x)$ is a homotopy connecting any two maps $f$ and $g$. However, if we require that the homotopy never go thru the origin except for $x=0$, then this does not work. I kind of feel that Lord is on the right track.

Comment: Yeah...the idea was  straight-line homotopies. The question asks for homotopies of maps, where the maps have a certain property; it did not specify that the intermediate stages of the homotopy ($P \mapsto F(P, s)$) must have that property too, although perhaps that was obviously intended (for everyone else who read the question). I thought the question, as written, was a decent kind of beginner's exercise in the idea of homotopies, and tried to give a gentle nudge on how to solve it. But I freely admit that my answer is not a correct solution to the (unwritten) question.